# 2 Layer PCBA routing strategy for high current design

Tags: pcb-design, layout, pcb-assembly, pcb-layers

I have a very simple pcba design. The only thing of value is that the traces will carry up to 30A of current.
I have already decided to increase copper thickness to 2 oz for improved current capacity.

Should i use wide copper traces or a full polygon pour/plane covering as much area as possible? Area doesn't necessarily equate to width.

Presently i am using the entirety of the 2nd layer as a ground as i can do all my routing on the top layer. Although certain low voltage traces (as shown in the bottom of the image) do break my copper plane up.

Trying to understand what the best practices are for such simple breakout board like designs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Area in itself is useless (if you have a big surface that is a "dead end", it doesn't hep carrying current).

What is useful, is to make traces as wide as you can at any location (even if it is only for a rather short distance, it will still reduce a little bit the global resistance). Doing a copper pour is an easy way to always get the maximal width (but at the cost of adding "dead ends" that will not help and might generate/pick-up noise). An "optimal" solution would be to manually do a "copper pour" without the dead ends.

From a more general point of view, make sure that your tracks are wide enough, and you will be fine. If you have some short section were you are a bit to narrow, you will have more resistance there, but you can try to compensate by making the rest of the track larger to maintain the global resistance of the path.

For your signals : if you manage to keep them all on the top side while having wide enough traces for the high current traces, then all is fine. If not, you might run some (partly) on the bottom face (ensuring the ground "traces" stay wide enough. Having them part of the length on one side and part on the other might help to keep power traces on both sides wide enough